# Is it possible see all the references to an object in execution time?

Tags: java, object, netbeans, reference

Is there a way to see all the references to an object in execution time?

I'm using Netbeans, does this feature exist in it?

EDIT: No problem in using profilers to do this, I only need know the references, no matters how.

Comment: Java does not maintain reference counts, and if it did, these references would not be exposed normally.

Comment: Not very clear ... Do you mean a tool like http://www.eclipse.org/mat/ ?

Comment: I think the question is asking how to use an IDE, not Java reference madness.  The Netbeans terminology is "Find Usages" and is supposed to be similar to Eclipse's "Find all references."

Comment: Can be in the IDE or another way. I informed the IDE because this can be there and I don't know.

Comment: @Renato: It's not clear what you're after - references to an *object* at execution time, or all the code which references a class or method.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Sorry, was not clear. I want the references in the execution time. All the refereces of a created object.

Comment: @Renato: Right. That's what I thought.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Ok, Netbeans show all the references to an object.

First, run the project in debug mode `CTRL + F5`, after, show the Loaded Classes `Alt + Shift + 4` or `Window->Debug->Loaded Classes`.

Choose the class will want to see the references and double click on it.

Pause the execution and there is.

In the top is the attributes of the object, and in the bottom, all references to it.

[image: In the bottom area where is "Referências" shows the references of the selected object]

Comment: Need help with the menu names, my Netbeans is in portuguese.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the answer to your question and sharing it with the rest of us.

Answer (score 16):

If you dump the heap and analyse it, you find all references. Profilers like VisualVM and YourKit can do this for you.

However, it is not possible to determine this dynamically. If you want to know all the things which refer to an object, you must maintain a collection of them yourself.

Comment: answer to the wrong question. Thankfully it was the answer to the question **I** am currently facing :-)

Answer (score 7):

In Netbeans you can use the **Find Usages** feature to see where a particular class may have been referenced inside of a particular project.

From the **Project Explorer**, select the class and right click > **Find Usages**.

The results looks a bit like the following image:

[image: Find Usage Results]

Answer (score 7):

> Sorry, was not clear. I want the references in the execution time. All
>   the refereces of a created object

Unfortunately, there is no such feature available in Java. But, there is a way of being notified that there is no more reference to an object at runtime.

The solution is to create a weak reference to the monitored object and associate it with a [reference queue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html#WeakReference%28T,%20java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue%29). When there will be no more hard reference to that object, the GC will sooner or later recollect it and enqueue the weak reference. You can check this with [isEnqueued()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ref/Reference.html#isEnqueued%28%29).

If you provide more information about your issue, may be we can give more tips & tricks.

**EDIT**

To control all references to an oject, you may use the Proxy Pattern. Instead of setting references to your connection object, you create a proxy object containing a private instance of the connection object. Then, have your code call the proxy who will call the connection object itself, instead of having direct references to the connection.

When you are done with the connection object, close it inside the proxy object. If other parts of the code still try to access that connection objects via the proxy, you will be able to detect it in the proxy when it is called.

It is a trick you can use to find which part of the code is still 'referencing' your object, so to speak.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just a bit curious about the references and a issue about connection remaining open after usage.

Comment: @Renato I have updated my solution with a suggestion to solve your issue.

Comment: @JVersty, Thanks for the answer. I am learning Java from a C++ background and have a nest of references that would be hard to clean up for JUnit purposes. Weak or Soft References look like they will help.