# All references of a Specific Instance in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging

I know about the all references and all instances functionality of Eclipse. But let us say that there are two instances of a specific type. Is there a way to find the references of a single instance or is there an Eclipse plugin that can achieve this?

If this cannot be achieved with Eclipse, is there some other tool that I can use to find the above information?

Comment: Netbeans-version of same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6155464/its-possible-see-all-the-references-to-an-object-in-execution-time